# PHP exec command "ng --version"

Tags: php, windows, exec, shell-exec, proc-open

I want to check if the user has install angular cli with running ng --version on PHP with exec, proc_open or shell_exec but return is empty.
I dont have problems if I execute in cmd or in terminal's Visual Studio Code in any path on Windows.

I'm use wampserver

Comment: `/path/to/ng --version`  of course you may not know so `locate ng` and parse that.

Comment: That's assuming Linux.

Comment: Update, srry I dont remember say my SO

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: No, at the end I have to skip this, because after to check this I need to run other command, and this command needs interaction, then I can't say Y or N when script ask

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it, and you have to consider what you will do if there are more than one found.  You can find it:

```
exec('where /r C:\ ng.exe', $paths);
```

And then if you really need the version, use the first one if it starts with `C:\`:

```
if(strpos($paths[0], 'C:\\') === 0) {
    exec($paths[0] . ' --version', $version);
}
print_r($version);
```

If it isn't found then `$paths[0]` should contain:

> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).